# Local website in Windows Phone / Windows 8 app

Tags: html, windows-phone-8, uiwebview, win-universal-app, storagefolder

I need a Windows Phone / Windows 8 app to display a static web site inducing images, CSSs, and JSs, i tried IUriToStreamResolver and StorageFolder, they worked for just one file (HTML page without images or external resources), so any help about the solution?

Comment: Why not use a web view?

Comment: Surly I am using WebView

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Here is the universar app project
http://1drv.ms/1mqiPLr
Kindly go to the windows phone project ShilpPage